# Cocoa error: Value of type 'NSButton' has no member 'setTitle'

Tags: cocoa, swift3

In Swift3, I have a button declared like:

```
 @IBOutlet  weak var transmitButton: NSButton!
```

I'm trying to set it's title:

```
func textViewDidChange(_ textView: NSTextView) {
        // If we're already transmitting, stop
        if transmitButton.state == NSOnState {
            transmitButton.setNextState()
            transmitButton.setTitle("On", for: .normal)
        }
    }
```

and I'm getting this error:

```
Value of type 'NSButton' has no member 'setTitle'
```

I'd appreciate any ideas/

Comment: All you need to do is set the title, no need for the setTitle: `transmitButton.title = "On"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is ***NS***Button there is no `setTitle:for:` method like in ***UI***Button, only a `title` property:

```
transmitButton.title = "On"
```

Comment: That was simple. I was banging my head for half an hour. Thanks very much.

Comment: It's always recommended to look into the documentation (⌥- or ⌘-click on the symbol) or ⇧⌘0 or ⇧⌘O and typing `NSButton`. There are many ways.